# Python output difference with and without print command

Tags: python, ipython

I am using `ipython notebook` with `Python 2.x` and I notice that usually there is a difference in how Python outputs if I use print command or do not use it. (Latter works only for last line in the cell)

For instance

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':list('ABCDEF')})
print df
df
```

Would give

[image: Output with and without print]

I like the second output which is nicely tabulated but it disappears if I use `print`

How do I get the output with `print` command with table around it as currently seen in output without `print` ?

Comment: This is true on the console as well. It's the difference between the `str` and `repr` functions in Python.

Comment: Thanks @user3697163 for pointing to the previous query. I tried to search  before posting but could not find it with keywords I was trying. I was sure this would have been discussed earlier.